# Chrome webkitRequestFileSystem and the file:// protocol

Tags: javascript, html, file, google-chrome

It seems impossible to use the webkitRequestFileSystem method from a local file without some sort of debug switch being passed to Chrome when it's run. Is there a way to ask a user for permission to save a text file (one that they have requested anyway) that is generated by javascript in a locally run html app/file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of, as long as it is not too much data and you don't need to support older versions of IE. You can do it with a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

[10000173](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000173/data-uri-for-csv-file-in-firefox-not-putting-csv-extension) shows the technique, and [283956](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri) has some answers on how you can't easily specify the filename that the browser chooses.

Comment: Unfortunately the data that needs to be exported will be quite significant in size most of the time.

Comment: I can't really do this but it's a great answer so I'm marking it as there answer.